# Bitrix. Добавить оценку товару или где находится таблица с данными рейтинга

Tags: php, mysql, битрикс

Всем привет!
Проблема следующая:
1) необходимо добавить оценку к товару через API.Bitrix, если такое возможно;
2) либо в какой таблице в БД хранятся данные рейтинга товара.
Речь идет про iblock.vote.
Ни поиск, ни документация ответа не дали :(

Answer (score 0):

Вы уже почти ответили на свой вопрос сами=)

Для рейтинга используется стандартный компонент - [bitrix.vote](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/content/iblock/components_2/iblock/iblock_vote.php)

Для того, что бы он заработал, достаточно в шаблоне со списком товаров (например bitrix.section) вызвать его и передать `ID товара, ID инфоблока и код товара`. Все эти значения уже есть в $arResult если Вы используете стандартный компонент. Если же у Вас самописный компонент, то добавьте недостающие значения.

Пример вызова компонента:

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:iblock.vote","stars",Array(
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $arItem['IBLOCK_ID'], //ID инфоболка
        "ELEMENT_ID" => $arItem['ID'], //ID товара
        "ELEMENT_CODE" => $arItem['CODE'], //код товара
        "MAX_VOTE" => "5",
        "VOTE_NAMES" => array("0","1","2","3","4"),
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "3600"
    )
);?>
```

У компонента bitrix.vote есть несколько стандартных шаблонов (ну или можно написать свой):

- .default - страшный шаблон  с селектом и кнопкой "голосовать" (не работает через ajax)
- ajax - выбор рейтинга квадратиками
- ajax_photo - хз, у меня не заработал
- flat - шаблон с выбором рейтинга "звездочками"
- stars - самый адкеватный шаблон (имхо), тоже со зведочкам

UPD:
Касательно второго вопроса: Где же все таки хранятся рейтинги к товарам в БД.
Если посмотреть код компонента iblock.vote, то видно, что он оперирует свойствами инфоблока.

Т.е. в инфоблок добавляются следующие `PROPERTY`:

- vote_count - Количество проголосовавших
- vote_sum - Сумма оценок
- rating - rating

И далее при добавления рейтинга работает следующая логика:

```
<?
$arProperties["vote_count"]["VALUE"] = intval($arProperties["vote_count"]["VALUE"])+1;
$arProperties["vote_sum"]["VALUE"] = intval($arProperties["vote_sum"]["VALUE"])+$RATING;
$arProperties["rating"]["VALUE"] = round(($arProperties["vote_sum"]["VALUE"]+31.25/5*$arParams["MAX_VOTE"])/($arProperties["vote_count"]["VALUE"]+10),2);
?>
```

Можно воспользоваться ей для добавления рейтинга например через компонент комментариев

Comment: Спасибо) Но проблема не в работе с компонентом. А в том, что заказчику несколько иная его реализация нужна. А именно - голосовать не клацая по звездам товара, а при написании отзыва (iblock.comments вроде). Может я что-то пропустил, но не нашел ничего похожего (Хотя в шаблоне комментов вроде есть фрагменты кода вызова голосовалки, но даже принудительно не могу их вызвать, поправив условия вызова).

Comment: Ну так в вопросе ничего не было про комментарии))) Задавая правильные вопросы, получишь правильные ответы как говорится)) В `bitrix:catalog.comments` параметр `SHOW_RATING` используется для оценки самих комментариев (уже после добавления коммента) поэтому тут нужно самостоятельно допиливать логику и шаблон компонента

Comment: @Andrey чуть обновил ответ, вдруг поможет)

Comment: @Andrey Напишите модуль под заказ. Если надо можете мне написать в ВК, если по цене договоримся - будет вам нужный модуль.